# How to set Extjs.grid.CheckColumn to disabled for read only?

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have a grid with check column and check column read my data but i cannot set it,i wondering how to set it with easy way.
I want my check column to become view only in my grid data how to set it?
below is my example code:

```
var chkColH = new Ext.grid.CheckColumn({
    header: '&nbsp;H',
    dataIndex: 'testing',
    resizable:false,
    disabled :true, //***I wan to disabled this check column in my grid for view only
    width: 25
});

colModel=new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([
    chkColH
]);


        xtype:'editorgrid',
        id:'theGrid',
        stripeRows:true,
        store:gridStore,
        colModel:colModel,
        trackMouseOver:false,
        columnLines:true,
        enableColumnMove:false,
        enableHdMenu:false,
        frame:true,
        disableSelection:true,
        plugins: [chkColH],
        sm:chkSM
```

Comment: see answer for working solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440216/how-do-i-disable-a-control-in-an-extjs-grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override **onMouseDown** to do nothing in **CheckColumn**:

```
var chkColH = new Ext.grid.CheckColumn({
    header: '&nbsp;H',
    dataIndex: 'testing',
    resizable:false,
    width: 25,
    onMouseDown : function(e, t){}
});
```

Comment: onMouseDown: `Ext.emptyFn` is shorter to type :-)

Answer (score 4):

`var chkColH = new Ext.grid.CheckColumn({
        header: 'Rerun',
        dataIndex: 'rerun',
        resizable:false,
        width: 25,
        disabled : true,
        disabledCls : 'x-item-enabled'
    });`

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your code base and use 'readonlycheckcolumn' xtype instead of 'checkcolumn' (tested with Ext 4.2):

```
Ext.define('Ext.grid.column.ReadOnlyCheckColumn', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.column.CheckColumn',
    alias: 'widget.readonlycheckcolumn',
    requires: ['Ext.grid.column.CheckColumn'],
    listeners: { beforecheckchange: function () { return false; } }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

in the checkcolumn config add this event:

```
processEvent: function () { return false; }
```

Comment: thanx. this should be the best answer. works on extjs 5.0.1. `processEvent: Ext.emptyFn`